# Permission denied when downgrading version node in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, downgrade

Im trying to downgrade node version with this command: `npm install -g n` but I have this error: `[Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/n']`

Then, I have to use this command to downgrade: `n 6.10.3`

How can I fix the permission denied error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo npm install -g n` to run the command as a super user.